# POSTing a PHP object/datastructure into another PHP file

Tags: php, json, post

I want to know if it would be possible to send a datastructure stored in the memory of a PHP file into another PHP file that is accepting a POST response to process?

For example, I can do a `var_dump($datastructure)` and it will print me everything. Can I actually somehow send this object as a text? Say encode this as a text or JSON object?

After doing this, can I pass this via POST into another PHP script to decode it into an object, that will let me do stuff with it?

Comment: You can easily do it with jquery-ajax.. You can json encode the data you have to send and then at the php page, you can simply decode it.  you can send the data either as a string or json object.

Comment: The best method would be to json_encode the structure.This way it wont get scrambled by the post request.

Comment: Look into the cURL extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php this will allow you to form HTTP POST request to your destination.